# Telerik Rad Bar Chart not plotting data

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radchart

I'm trying to create a clustered bar chart using Rad Chart. My data model looks very simple.

```
Name: string
CurrencyValue: decimal
Count: int

<telerik:RadChart runat="server" ID="rcMain" OnLoad="rcMain_OnLoad" DefaultType="bar" >
            <Series>
                <telerik:ChartSeries Type="Bar" DataYColumn="CurrencyValue" DataYColumn2="Count">
                </telerik:ChartSeries>
            </Series>
         </telerik:RadChart>
```

I can only get it to plot 1 of the columns. It won't plot both. I've tried setting `GroupDataColumn` to Name with no avail. How can I configure the chart to plot both columns?

Answer (score 0):

here is the code you need:

```
<telerik:RadChart ID="RadChart1" SkinsOverrideStyles="True" runat="server" 
                Width="900px" Height="600px" DefaultType="StackedBar" Skin="DeepBlue">
<Series>
                    <telerik:ChartSeries Name="Currency Value" DataYColumn="CurrencyValue" />
<telerik:ChartSeries Name="Count" DataYColumn="Count" />
</Series>
</telerik:RadChart>
```

here is the output:

[image]

hope this helps.